# up button doesn't go to parent activity

Tags: android, up-button

I have an app with several activities. The up button created by

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

works on all the activities except for one. I've checked the manifest and I can see the parent is set correctly.

Code from activity where the up button doesn't work:

```
package com.icenibees.apiarymanager;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.icenibees.apiarymanager.sample.SampleDataProvider;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ApiaryDetails extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    public static final String LOGTAG="APIARYMANAGER";
    public String apiaryIDDelete = "";

    AMDBDataSource mDataSource;

    EditText updateApiaryNameInput;
    EditText updateApiaryLocationInput;
    EditText updateApiaryDescriptionInput;
    EditText updateApiarySetupDateInput;
    EditText updateApiaryNotesInput;
    String updateApiaryidInput;

private TextView tvName, tvDescription, tvLocation, tvSetupDate, tvNotes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_apiary_details);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mDataSource = new AMDBDataSource(this);
        mDataSource.open();

        final AMClasses.Apiary updateApiary = new AMClasses.Apiary();

//        String apiaryId = getIntent().getExtras().getString(ApiaryItemAdapter.APIARY_ID_KEY);
//        AMClasses.Apiary item = SampleDataProvider.apiaryItemMap.get(apiaryId);

        final AMClasses.Apiary item = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(ApiaryItemAdapter.APIARY_RECORD);
        if (item == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("No data record received!?!");
        }

        tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvApiaryName);
        tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvApiaryLocation);
        tvSetupDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvApiarySetupDate);
        tvDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvApiaryDescription);
        tvNotes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvApiaryNotes);

        tvName.setText(item.getApiaryname());
        tvLocation.setText(item.getApiarylocation());
        tvSetupDate.setText(item.getApiarysetupdate());
        tvDescription.setText(item.getApiarydescription());
        tvNotes.setText(item.getApiarynotes());

        apiaryIDDelete = item.getApiaryid();

        Button updateApiaryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateApiary);
        updateApiaryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                                  @Override
                                                  public void onClick(View view){

                                                      updateApiaryidInput = item.getApiaryid();
                                                      updateApiaryNameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvApiaryName);
                                                      updateApiaryLocationInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvApiaryLocation);
                                                      updateApiaryDescriptionInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvApiaryDescription);
                                                      updateApiarySetupDateInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvApiarySetupDate);
                                                      updateApiaryNotesInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvApiaryNotes);


                                                      //updateApiary.setApiaryid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

                                                      updateApiary.setApiaryid(updateApiaryidInput);
                                                      updateApiary.setApiaryname(updateApiaryNameInput.getText().toString());
                                                      updateApiary.setApiarylocation(updateApiaryLocationInput.getText().toString());
                                                      updateApiary.setApiarydescription(updateApiaryDescriptionInput.getText().toString());
                                                      updateApiary.setApiarysetupdate(updateApiarySetupDateInput.getText().toString());
                                                      updateApiary.setApiarynotes(updateApiaryNotesInput.getText().toString());

                                                      Log.i(LOGTAG, "Apiary ID to be updated: " + updateApiary.getApiaryid());
                                                      Log.i(LOGTAG, "Update Apiary Name: " + updateApiary.getApiaryname());
                                                      Log.i(LOGTAG, "Update Apiary Location: " + updateApiary.getApiarylocation());
                                                      Log.i(LOGTAG, "Update Apiary Description: " + updateApiary.getApiarydescription());
                                                      Log.i(LOGTAG, "Update Apiary Setup Date: " + updateApiary.getApiarysetupdate());
                                                      Log.i(LOGTAG, "Update Apiary Notes: " + updateApiary.getApiarynotes());

                                                      mDataSource.updateApiary2DB(updateApiary);

                                                      Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                                                              "Apiary updated", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                              .setAction("Action",null).show();
                                                      thread.start();



                                                  }
                                              }
        );


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    //ACTIVITY TIMER CLOSER

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2500); // As I am using LENGTH_LONG in Toast
                ApiaryDetails.this.finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };


    //DELETE MENU

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_edit_apiary, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // SETTINGS MENU CASE STATEMENTS

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_apiary_delete:

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                builder.setMessage("Please confirm you want to delete the apiary?");
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_delete);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        mDataSource.deleteApiary(apiaryIDDelete);    // Delete Apiary Row
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                                "Apiary deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action",null).show();
                        thread.start();

                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //DATE PICKER CODE

    public void datePickerEditApiary(View view){

        NewApiary.DatePickerFragment fragment = new NewApiary.DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date");
    }



    public void setDate(final Calendar calendar){

        final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.UK);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvApiarySetupDate)).setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }



    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        setDate(cal);
    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(),year, month, day);
        }

    }


}
```

---

Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".EditApiary"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit__apiary"
            android:parentActivityName=".ApiarySetup"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.icenibees.apiarymanager.ApiarySetup" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ApiaryDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_apiary_details"
            android:parentActivityName=".EditApiary"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.icenibees.apiarymanager.EditApiary" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditHive"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_hive"
            android:parentActivityName=".ApiarySetup"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.icenibees.apiarymanager.ApiarySetup" />
        </activity>
```

Comment: please post the relevant parft of code..

Comment: check the theme associated with that Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see

> getSupportActionBar()

So, you are using AppCompatActivity instance

Probably, you should override onOptionsItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
        //Or another code here
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, you can add parent activity inside AndroidManifest.xml like this:
*API 16+*

```
<activity
  ....
  android:parentActivityName="activity_class_name" />
```

Comment: Great thanks Dmitry, worked a treat. Did the up button stop working because this is the first activity that I'm using a menu in the action bar?